# Customize Password Set Screen once user logs in for the first time - Communities

Tags: apex, lightning-experience, customer-community, passwords, theme-branding

Once the user logs in for the first time, they are redirected to set a password. Can we customize that page or redirect users to a new Page to achieve Client Branding in Communities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In communities, we can customize both the set password and reset password page.
Go to Setup> All Sites> Builder>Administration>Login & Registration. Under password Pages section choose your custom Visualforce page for **Reset Password**. Whenever the user is created in communities and they recieve email, the email link will open the the selected VF page.

There is default VF page(changePassword) available which you can customize as per the requirement.